# Detecting Front and Back camera in windows 8 tabs

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I am developing a metro style app using c# and xaml. For a particular task i need to detect which cam(front or back) is currently capturing. Is there any way to detect front cam or back cam in winrt. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Using indexes on the DeviceInformationCollection won't be a reliable solution:

1. Sometimes front camera will be index 0 and sometimes 1, after testing on the surface 2 a few times it seems to be kind of random.
2. User could use the USB port to connect an other webcam so you could end up with more than 2 items in your collection without any clue which camera is which index.

Having the same problem as you this is how I solved it:

```
// Still need to find all webcams
DeviceInformationCollection webcamList = await eviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture)

// Then I do a query to find the front webcam
DeviceInformation frontWebcam = (from webcam in webcamList
     where webcam.EnclosureLocation != null 
     && webcam.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Front
     select webcam).FirstOrDefault();

// Same for the back webcam
DeviceInformation backWebcam = (from webcam in webcamList
     where webcam.EnclosureLocation != null 
     && webcam.EnclosureLocation.Panel == Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back
     select webcam).FirstOrDefault();
```

In this exemple I used Linq queries but it works the same with a foreach on "webcamList".

Just look on each DeviceInformation the ***.EnclosureLocation.Panel*** property, which is a *Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel* enum. The rest is obvius, Front for the front camera, Back for the back one.

Be also carefull to check if *.EnclosureLocation* is null or not, using an USB webcam it seems to be null most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
 DeviceInformationCollection videoCaptureDevices = await eviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
```

If the videoCaptureDevices count is zero ,there is no camera attached.
And if camera count is 2 , then there will be both Front & back cameras.

If you initializing camera operation with `videoCaptureDevices [0]`, that will be using Front Camera, and will be Back Camera if it is using `videoCaptureDevices [1]` .